# Editing the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the picture, you will see a table at the beginning that contains **NULL** in the **Rounds column**. After that, **it shows 9th**. How can I *edit* the data **from 9th to NULL**?

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Rank]
      ,[Player]
      ,[Team]
      ,[Position]
      ,[Rounds]
  FROM [Yahoo Fantansy Basketball 2020-2021].[Players].[Rank]
  ORDER BY [Rank] ASC;
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server and SQLite? You're not using both are you.

Comment: It seems you would benefit more from, and learn faster, if you found yourself a few SQL tutorials. Updates are a very basic part of SQL - even the official documentation will explain how to do this.

Comment: Thank you @DaleK, I have been watching tutorials on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Players.Rank SET Rounds = NULL WHERE Rounds = '9th'
```

Comment: Is this in the SELECT statment?

Comment: That would go in the `UPDATE` statement